# How to retrieve data from a sql server stored procedure using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im trying to get data from a stored procedure but it gives me an error, the stored procedure when I passed some value looks like this

```
     `DECLARE   @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_PersonAlerts_Get]
    @Active = 1,
    @StartWeek = NULL,
    @PersonID = 0

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO`
```

the Php Code to retrieve a resultset is:

```
<?php

    $var_Active = 1;

    $var_PersonID = 0;

    $var_StartWeek = null;



    $params = array(
                array($var_Active, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($var_StartWeek, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array($var_PersonID, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)

                );

    $sp_name = "Exec sp_PersonAlerts_Get @Active = ?, @StartWeek = ?,    @PersonID=?";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $gaSql['link'], $sp_name, $params);// or die("<pre>" . print_r(sqlsrv_errors()) . "<br><br>$sp_name</pre>");



while($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $stmt )){  
    $var_StartDate       = $obj->StartDate;

echo $var_StartDate;

    }


?>
```

It gives me this message :

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 01000 [SQLSTATE] => 01000 [1] => 0 
[code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQl Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-24, @EndWk: 2017-09-30 [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC     Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]@StartWeek: 2017-09-24, @EndWk: 2017-09-30 ) )
```

Thanks in advance , I have already tested the connection and the stored procedure and their both ok but I can't seem to find the error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

So the sql error 0100 means a warning but The default setting is to treat all warnings as errors, so the query will fail.

using `sqlsrv_configure('WarningsReturnAsErrors',0);` seems to work. Found the answer here:

[How do I make sqlsrv ignore messages returned from database?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e214e95a-390f-42f8-bac3-584906ce85d4/how-do-i-make-sqlsrv-ignore-messages-returned-from-database?forum=sqldriverforphp)